# What layout should I use

Tags: android, android-layout

So I am relativity new to android besides some pet projects, and what I want to do with my new project is show an image that consist of a hexagonal shape and on the boarders of the image show some radio buttons. Is this possible/what is the best way to go about this? I was thinking I could do it with absolute view do you guys think this is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use AbsoluteLayout as it is deprecated. And using it will make your app's UI look too different of different devices.
2. For your current requirement from what I can pick-up, use a RelativeLayout as it would provide a little more flexibility (when compared to LinearLayout)
3. There is no best UI Layout. What works best for you is the one you must be using.

Comment: Wasn't I the first one to suggest to use a RelativeLayout? ;)

Comment: I up voted both of u's I do appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

relative layout would be the best solution for your problem, but you may need to use some "dummy" views to align your real views properly.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the api and I see that it has a rotation property which I did not see before so I think this will work perfectly :)